# can Log.d("","") Logs, be seen in smartphone after installation?

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

If you use `Log.d("hussi","hussi"):` then we can see it in logcat .

but after the application is installed in the smartphone ,
can we see the logs somewhere in the phon , if yes , then where ??
also if there is any other way to write logs which we can trace in smartphones ?

Comment: I think so yes. The LogCat has a setting of All Messages which has no filters and you can actually see software log messages go through there. Though I'm not entirely sure about that.

Comment: All of your logs will be visible even in a production app unless you make use of proguard to hide them. There are applications in the store that can help and show logs, but since ICS android version (I guess so) you only be able to read them in a rooted phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the Log details as text or xml format and will be stored in SD card.

You should use

**https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/**

Log4j Implementation in Android give you desired result.

**You can use Log.debug(),log.error(), log.info()**

All kind of log you can store in text or xml file.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) (emph mine).

> **Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime.** Error, warning and info logs are always kept.

Answer (score 1):

Using this should print the logcat output to a text file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("echo logcat >> /sdcard/log.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use logcat for the same. Samsung ships with an application to take log dumps. You can access it using the keystring *#9900# . Take log dumps from there and save it to sdcard for using later. AFAIK this behavior is Manufacturer specific.